# Crystal Reports PrintToPrinter has stopped working after Windows Update installed patch related to PrintNightmare

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

We have an ASP.NET Web application installed (.NET FW v4.x based) and working on Windows Server 2012. The Crystal Reports v13.0.20 runtime is installed and the web application uses this to preview reports on screen and to print reports to networked printers. We use `PrintToPrinter` in `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`. Code included below.

Printing was working a few days ago, i.e. the printers were printing reports correctly.

Yesterday, Windows Update installed updates related to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-10-2021-kb5005043-os-build-14393-4583-709d481e-b02a-4eb9-80d9-75c4b8170240 which addresses the PrintNighmare vulnerability. After this update, printing stopped working.

Today we uninstalled this update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-10-2021-kb5005043-os-build-14393-4583-709d481e-b02a-4eb9-80d9-75c4b8170240 from the server and the printers are able to print reports again.

Has anyone seen this or found a way to have the critical update in-place but allow reports to print from the above scenario?

Code:

```
        Using cr As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
            cr.FileName = mReportName
            cr.Load(mReportName)
            cr.PrintOptions.PrinterName = mPrinterName
            cr.PrintToPrinter(mCopies, True, 1, 1000)
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "local printers". You can use "local printers" even if you want to print to a shared printer (\servername\printername). The driver is then locally installed, and not fetched/updated from the remote server.

1. Open “Devices and Printers”
2. Click “Add a printer” (on the top)
3. Select “Add a local printer”
4. Select “Create a new port”, select “Local Port” (port type)
5. Port Name: enter the network path to the printer in format \printservername\queuename
   Example2: \server1.mydsomain.com\printer1
6. Select the printer driver (driver installation)

You might need to run your IIS app pool as a user (service account) with right to print to the remote queue.

--

Or bypass the Microsoft change with:

Add a registry value to get back the "old behavior" before the KB5005043
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint]
-> "RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators"=dword:00000000

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I did see that workaround in the Microsoft KB but I'm looking for a way to print from Crystal but also leave the patch in place. Uninstalling or adding in this registry entry workaround which still leaves servers vulnerable is going to be a non-starter for some of our customers. And I still don't understand why a simple print routine breaks with the security patch installed. What is that `cr.PrintToPrinter` is doing that butts heads with the MS patch?

Comment: Use "local printers".
You can use "local printers" even if you want to print to a shared printer (\\servername\printername). (The driver is then locally installed, and not fetched/updated from the remote server)
https://pattersonsupport.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/21672/~/install-a-shared-printer-as-a-local-port-device
You might need to run your IIS app pool as a user (service account) with right to print to the remote queue.